# What C instructions do I need to use to get gcc's x86-64 autovectorizer to output pshufb opcodes?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, sse, simd, auto-vectorization

I'd like gcc's autovectorization (i.e. not intrinsics) to convert 0xPQ to the 64-bit value 0xPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQ using the ssse3 opcode pshufb. However, even though I can see pshufb opcodes being output by gcc for other uses (so the compiler is definitely able to output it), I can't work out the series of C instructions needed to trigger it for this particualr case.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html

Comment: Michael: ah, I'm sorry my question wasn't clearer. I'm trying to use gcc's autovectorization (i.e. leaving the compiler to handle the vectorization code), rather than use intrinsic functions such as __builtin_ia32_pshufb128(). Apologies!

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that `pshufb` will be the most efficient solution, unless you intend to have the result in the lower part of an `xmm` register. If you do, provide an actual usage example.

If you write something like:

```
long long foo(char x)
{
    long long ret;
    std::memset(&ret, x, sizeof ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Both gcc and clang essentially just multiply `x` by `0x0101010101010101` which is as fast as a `pshufb` (assuming you have that value in a register already). However, with `imul` you have the result already in a general purpose register (and no additional `movq` is required).

Godbolt compilation results: https://godbolt.org/z/dTvcsM (the `-msse3` makes no difference, nor do other compilation options, as long as it is at least `-O1`).

Comment: `pshufb` is SSSE3, not SSE3.  The extra S stands for "Supplemental".  Thanks,  Intel. :/

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, you are right. But passing `-mssse3` or even `-O3 -mavx2` does not change the compiler output, either. It may be different if source or target were a SIMD register (or memory) -- but the OP provided too little information what his actual use case is.

Comment: Right.  I can get clang to emit `pshufb` as part of a larger memset (like 32 bytes to a `char*out` arg), but gcc's inline memset is less good.  https://godbolt.org/z/MGVK29 (especially with -march=knl it's hilariously bad, one mulx per store).  IDK if we could get gcc to use it when auto-vectorizing something with `char` data.  Hmm, maybe packing from dword to byte in one step?  Nope, it uses packssdw/packuswb which is probably for the best.  Maybe with independent packs of 16->4...

Comment: Here are some experiments that autovectorize (under gcc 9.2) but produce insanely prolix code, that really should (somehow) just be pshufb ops: https://godbolt.org/z/r8p7VZ

Comment: Looking more closely, I suspect that gcc is refusing to do a 64-bit multiply by 0x0101010101010101 for some unknown reason, and so it is choosing (in the first attempt) to synthesize it by 8 bit shift-and-adds, then 16-bit shift-and-adds, and then finally 32-bit shift-and-adds. But if it knows all that information already, why doesn't it use pshufb? It's a mystery to me. :-(